# Is there a way to use vuetify's autocomplete with full text search implemented on the backend?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js, vuex

My `v-autocomplete`:

```
           <v-autocomplete
              v-model="productSearchData.selected"
              outlined
              return-object
              item-value="id"
              :search-input.sync="productSearchData.query"
              :items="productSearchData.items"
              chips
              multiple
              deletable-chips
              small-chips
              dense
              cache-items
            />
```

And `productSearchData`:

```
productSearchData: {
    selected: [],
    query: null,
    items: [],
},
```

`productSearchData.items` is correctly filled with data from the backend based on `productSearchData.query` like this:

```
      {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "The great red dress"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "The awesome white collar"
      }
```

Now, if I type `amazing shoes` on the autocomplete (`productSearchData.query`), the backend correctly returns only one result, so `productSearchData.items` will be:

```
      {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "The amazing blue shoes"
      }
```

But the problem is, since the search query is not in the items (the typed `amazing shoes` is not the same as the option `The amazing blue shoes`) the v-autocomplete will display nothing even if the correct data is there.

Is there an easy solution to this?

I already tried with some of the autocomplete props with no success. (using vuetify 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom filter function using the [`:filter`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-filter) prop:

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :filter="filterItems"
  ...
```

The function receives the autocomplete item, the query text and, conveniently, the text from the item. There, you can split your query string and search for the individual parts, i.e. "amazing" and "shoes":

```
filterItems(item, queryText, itemText){
  const itemTextLc = itemText.toLocaleLowerCase()
  return queryText.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').every(q => itemTextLc.includes(q))
}
```

If you filter the items in the back end and all results are valid, you can just have your filter function return `true`.

If you also want to highlight the query text in the dropdown, it is a bit more work, I don't think Vuetify supports this out of the box. Have a look at the snippet:

```js
const highlightClass = 'v-list-item__mask'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      productSearchData: {
          selected: [],
          query: null,
          items: [
            {"id": "1", "text": "The great red dress"},
            {"id": "3", "text": "The amazing blue shoes"}
          ],
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterItems(item, queryText, itemText){
      const itemTextLc = itemText.toLocaleLowerCase()
      return queryText.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').every(q => itemTextLc.includes(q))
    },
    parseItemText(itemText, queryText){
      const highlightPositions = this.extractHighlightPositions(itemText, queryText)
      const parsed = []
      let pos = 0
      for (const {start, length} of highlightPositions){
        if (pos < start){
          this.pushSubstring(parsed, itemText, pos, start)
        }
        this.pushSubstring(parsed, itemText, start, start+length, highlightClass)
        pos = start + length
      }
      if (pos < itemText.length){
        this.pushSubstring(parsed, itemText, pos, itemText.length)
      }
      return parsed
    },
    pushSubstring(arr, str, start, end, cls){
      const text = str.substring(start, end)
      arr.push({text, class: cls})
    },
    extractHighlightPositions(itemText, queryText){
      if (!queryText||!itemText) return []
      const queryWords = queryText.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ')
      return queryWords
        .map(qw => ({start: itemText.indexOf(qw), length: qw.length}))
        .sort((a,b) => a.start - b.start || a.length - b.length)
        .reduce((agg,positionData) => {
          if (agg.length === 0) return [positionData]
          const {start, length} = positionData
          const last = agg[agg.length-1]
          if (start > last.start + last.length){
            agg.push(positionData)
          } else {
            last.length = Math.max(last.length, start - last.start + length)
          }
          return agg 
        }, [])
    }
    
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="productSearchData.selected"
            outlined
            return-object
            item-value="id"
            :search-input.sync="productSearchData.query"
            :items="productSearchData.items"
            chips
            multiple
            deletable-chips
            small-chips
            dense
            cache-items
            :filter=filterItems
          >
            <template
              #item="{parent, item, on:{click, ...rootOn}, attrs:{disabled, inputValue, ripple, ...rootAttrs}}"
              v-on="rootOn"
              v-bind="rootAttrs"
            >
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-simple-checkbox
                  :disabled="disabled"
                  :value="inputValue"
                  :ripple="ripple"
                  @click="click"
                >
                </v-simple-checkbox>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-title>
                <span
                  v-for="segment in parseItemText(item[parent.itemText], parent.searchInput)"
                  :class="segment.class"
                >{{segment.text}}</span>
              </v-list-item-title>
            </template>
          </v-autocomplete>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```